# Kafka Consumer Vs Apache Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, avro, kafka-consumer-api, apache-flink

I did a poc in which I read data from Kafka using spark streaming. But our organization is either using Apache Flink or Kafka consumer to read data from Apache kafka as a standard process. So I need to replace Kafka streaming with Kafka consumer or Apache Flink. In my application use case, I need to read data from kafka, filter json data and put fields in cassandra, so the recommendation is to use Kafka consumer rather than flink/other streamings as I don't really need to do any processing with Kafka json data. So I need your help to understand below questions:

1. Using Kafka consumer, can I achieve same continuous data read as we do in case of spark streaming or flink?
2. Is kafka consumer sufficient for me considering I need to read data from kafka, deserialize using avro scehma, filter fields and put in cassandra?
3. Kafka consumer application can be created using kafka consumer API, right?
4. Is there any down sides in my case if I just use Kafka consumer instead of Apache flink?

Comment: You should also consider using Kafka's Streams API.  This is much more powerful than Kafka's consumer API. https://kafka.apache.org/0102/documentation/streams and http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/

Comment: How do you plan to deploy your application? Are there any systems already in place for deploying "stuff" in your org?
What are the long-term plans for the system? Do you intend to keep using it just for ingestion into Cassandra, or are there plans to perform any computation on the data in the stream?

Comment: @rmetzger: Plan is to deploy it on independent cluster where consumer API job can run. We don't have any existing system to deploy stuff, it will new environment. Idea is to just to read data from kafka, convert into json using avro, filter required fields and store into cassandra, no computation. Your suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Mh :) Its hard to suggest anything. It depends on the knowledge you have in your team. If most of them have used Hadoop YARN before, I would deploy Flink using YARN.
If you are using your own system to deploy and monitor JVMs in a cluster, you can consider Kafka Streams.
I would actually suggest to try out both systems and see what works better for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let's take a look at [Flinks Kafka Connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/kafka.html), And [Spark Streaming with Kafka](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html), both of them use Kafka Consumer API(either simple API or high level API) inside to consume messages from Apache Kafka for their jobs.

So, regarding to your questions:

1. Yes
2. Yes. However, if you use Spark, you can consider to use [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector), which helps to save data into Cassandara efficiently
3. Right
4. As mentioned above, Flink also uses Kafka consumer for its job. Moreover, it is a distributed stream and batch data processing, it helps to process data efficiently after consuming from Kafka. In your cases, to save data into Cassandra, you can consider to use [Flink Cassandra Connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/cassandra.html) rather than coding by yourselve.

Comment: Thanks for you inputs! As per your reply seems like we don't have any in-built API to store data in Cassandra in case I use Kafka consumer API to read data from Kafka? Can you please confirm?

Comment: You can use Kafka-Cassandra connector from Confluent.io: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-the-perfect-match/, or from community: https://github.com/tuplejump/kafka-connect-cassandra.